# graphviz - prevent nodes and edges overlapping without splines

Tags: graphviz

I have a simple fdp graph laid out in graphviz, with a bunch of nodes (rectangle and diamond shaped) having fixed positions, and some of those nodes have child nodes (oval shaped) that I want to be arranged around them automatically.

I want all edges in it to be straight, with no curves or polylines or anything (i.e. as given by `splines=false`), but I also want those child nodes to not overlap with edges between nodes with fixed positions. The fixed positions are used as I need edges between the fixed nodes to be fully vertical or horizontal. This is something that I probably can achieve by iterating over different `start` values and hoping that the next one will not have overlaps, but so far this is a bit tiresome.

```
digraph G {

###GRAPH
layout=fdp
overlap=false
dpi=150
splines=false
inputscale=0.4
# fdp specific:
K=0.50
maxiter=2000
start=1251

###OBJECTS
node[shape=rectangle width=1.0 height=0.4 fixedsize=true]

vendor[label="Поставщик" pos="3,1!"
]

item[label="Товар" pos="0,2!"
]

post[label="Поставка" pos="2,2!"
]

check[label="Чек" pos="1,1!"
]

prod[label="Продажа" pos="0,0!"
]


###SUBOBJECTS
node[shape=oval width=1.5 height=0.5]
edge[arrowhead=none]

{
vendork[label=<<u>ID поставщика</u>>] "Название\nпоставщика" "Контакт\nдля связи"
}->vendor

{
itemk[label=<<u>ID товара</u>>]
Название Тип Подтип Характеристики "Розничная цена"
}->item

{
postk[label=<<u>ID записи</u>>] post1[label="ID товара"]
post2[label="Кол-во"]       post3[label="Цена поставки"]
post4[label="Дата"]     post5[label="Квитанция"]
}->post

{
prodk[label=<<u>ID продажи</u>>]    prod1[label="ID товара"]
prod2[label="Кол-во"]           prod3[label="Цена\nпродажи"]
prod4[label="Чек"]
}->prod

{
checkk[label=<<u>ID чека</u>>] Дата Кассир "Сумма" "НДС" "Итого" "Вид оплаты"
}->check

###CONNECTIONS
node[shape=diamond]
edge[arrowhead=open]

vendorpost[label="Поставляет" pos="3,2!"
]
vendorpost->vendor
vendorpost->post[arrowhead=openopen]

postitem[label="Поставлен" pos="1,2!"
]
postitem->item
postitem->post[arrowhead=openopen]

itemprod[label="Продан" pos="0,1!"
]
itemprod->item
itemprod->prod[arrowhead=openopen]

prodcheck[label="Включает" pos="1,0!"
]
prodcheck->prod[arrowhead=openopen]
prodcheck->check
}
```

(forgive the cyrillics)

I am compiling with no additional parameters (i.e. `dot -Tpng graph.gv > graph.png`). So far, I get this.

[image: Result with fdp]

I've tried using neato instead as well, but, in most cases, it gives a pretty weird result, where it seems like it completely ignores the fixed node positions, and draws the child nodes whereever it wants:

[image: Result with neato]

I went through the list of attributes in [the documentation](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html), and so far none seem to address node/edge overlapping besides `splines` (unless I've missed something). What should I do to achieve the result I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues:

- **layout=fdp** causes the fdp layout engine to be used, no matter what the command line says
- Use **neato -n** if you want to nail down the node position (see below)
- by adding a **!** to the position you are nailing down the pos (it won't change)
- **dot** is not useful here, it is directional (top-down)

If you remove all the **!**, I think you will get what you want.
[image]

Comment: I use `layout=fdp` as I use `vimdot` script to edit those graphs, which doesn't seem to allow for `-n` parameter and uses `dot` by default. Also, I want all edges between "parent" nodes to be either perfectly vertical or horizontal, hence the fixed placement. I could use `dot`, but it is intended for other types of graphs, and would (as far as I understood) place each "child" node in odd looking rows or columns. I did make another graph like this in `dot`, but it was way too much of a hassle with adding invisible edges to keep it working. The invisible support beams with fdp seem nicer though.

Answer (score 0):

So far, one solution I've found is by adding invisible stretched out nodes that cover each edge that is fixed(i.e. between two nodes with fixed positions) by appending this to the graph:

```
###NO VERTICAL/HORIZONTAL EDGE/NODE INTERSECT HACK
node[style=invis]
node[width=0.1 height=2.0]
t1[label="" pos="0,1.5!"]
t2[label="" pos="0,0.5!"]
t3[label="" pos="1,0.5!"]
t4[label="" pos="3,1.5!"]
node[width=2.0 height=0.1]
t5[label="" pos="2.5,2!"]
t6[label="" pos="1.5,2!"]
t7[label="" pos="0.5,2!"]
t8[label="" pos="0.5,0!"]
node[style=normal]
```

And this does what I want, i.e. removes all overlaps with fixed edges:

[image: result with support beam hack]

However, this is limited only to edges that are perfectly vertical/horizontal(note that there is still at least 1 overlap in "child" nodes), and overall seems like a really hacky solution as I have to add/change those "support beams" every time I add/change any more nodes to my graph. Is there a better solution to this?